# What is the difference between align and equation environment when I only want to display one line of equation?

Tags: equations, environments, align

I am typesetting a physics document, and sometimes I need to type equations of several lines while in most cases I only need to type one-line formula. So is it OK if I always use `align` environment instead of switching between `align` and `equation` What are their differences?

Comment: The spacing above and below will be different. So for one liners, you should use `equation` *not* `align`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

The *vertical* spacing is different, but only noticeable in certain instances. To see this, consider all the possible ways in which you can have text around these displays:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

Long/long line before/after display:

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum.
  \begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{equation}
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum.
  \begin{align}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{align}
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{minipage}

\hrulefill

Long/short line before/after display:

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum.
  \begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{equation}
  Lrm.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum.
  \begin{align}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{align}
  Lrm.
\end{minipage}

\bigskip

\hrulefill

\bigskip

Short/long line before/after display:

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lrm:
  \begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{equation}
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lrm:
  \begin{align}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{align}
  Lorem ipsum.
\end{minipage}

\hrulefill

Short/short line before/after display:

\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lrm:
  \begin{equation}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{equation}
  Lrm.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  Lrm:
  \begin{align}
    f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
  \end{align}
  Lrm.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The above showcases the use of all combinations of long/short pieces of text immediately before/after the display; left column denotes the use of an `equation` and the right column uses the equivalent with an `align`. These influence the use of TeX's display skips:

```
\abovedisplayskip% If the line ending above the display is not short
\abovedisplayshortskip% ... If the line ending above the display is short
\belowdisplayskip% If the line ending below the display is not short
\belowdisplayshortskip% ... If the line ending below the display is short
```

It's clear that a short line *above* `align` is interpreted differently than that of `equation` (compare the bigger skips above equations (6) and (8) in relation to that of equations (5) and (7)).

That's not all though, and the above image is slightly misleading in that sense. If the `minipage`s where aligned to the `[b]`ottom rather than the `[t]`op

[image]

you'll see that even the skip *below* the `align` is interpreted differently when the line following the display is short.

---

Is it okay to use a single equation inside an `align`? Sure, if you're comfortable with the look of it. With surrounding text there's you could expect there to be long ("not short") lines on both sides of the display, in which case `align` "performs" similarly to `equation` (equations (1)-(4) above).

Comment: This is (partially) wrong. It is always _irrelevant_ whether a long or short line _follows_ the display, as your final examples show. What triggers (in non-aligned displays) the difference between `\belowdisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip` is whether the line **before** the display is long or short. This seems paradoxical, but goes for a more aesthetically pleasing effect. TeXbook page 189.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments, the only difference is the spacing of the formulas. You should attempt to use `equation` when possible, and `align` when you have multi-line formulas.

Also: `equation` throws an error when you have an `&` inside the environment, so look out for that when converting between the two.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.