# Difference between single-line align and equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, environments

What is the difference between the align environment with only a single line and the equation environment?
If there is no difference, can we use align all the time since equation then just becomes a special case of align?

Comment: never use 1-line `align`, the spacing will be all wrong, Ths is a duplicate I'll see if I can find the existing question...

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239550/what-is-the-difference-between-align-and-equation-environment-when-i-only-want-t/239562#239562 (although the answer there could be clearer that a 1-line `align`  is wrong)